# How to set timezone inside alpine base docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, timezone

I want to set time zone in my docker container. I follow this article but can't find working solution for alpine base image.
Could you please guide me?

https://dev.to/0xbf/set-timezone-in-your-docker-image-d22

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You need to install the `tzdata` package and then set the enviroment variable `TZ` to a timezone. ([List with all the timezones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones#List))

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata
ENV TZ=Europe/Copenhagen
```

Output

```
$ docker run --rm alpine date
Tue Aug 31 09:52:08 UTC 2021

$ docker run --rm myimage date
Tue Aug 31 11:52:13 CEST 2021
```

Comment: Thx so much, this problem was killing me today!

Comment: note that you can save some image size by: `RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata`

Comment: I found that simply setting an `env_file` on `docker-compose` containing `TZ=Europe/Copenhagen` did the job. No need to install `tzdata`, at least on Python and nginx Alpine based images.

Comment: @henrikstroem Try it on the base Alpine image. It needs tzdata. The images you've tried must have it installed already. I checked nginx:alpine and it has tzdata installed.

Answer (score 14):

This is my `Dockerfile` and it works:

```yaml
FROM alpine:latest

# Essentials
RUN apk add -U tzdata
ENV TZ=America/Santiago
RUN cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Santiago /etc/localtime
```

you have to replace **'America/Santiago'** with your timezone

Comment: Is there a reason to create /etc/localtime? It works fine with `tzdata`and `ENV TZ=<zone>`

Comment: Hi @JesperGrannLaursen , thank you for your question. The simple answer is that it is necessary for some applications to accurately display the correct time in the specified time zone. However, as you say, it's not necessary one hundred percent. That depends on what you're doing exactly. I added that line because it works with my specific configuration in my project, but you can remove it if you want.