# Python datetime.now() not giving correct system time

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timestamp

Migrated one of my python fastapi application to an Alpine based image running Alpine 3.17 and python 3.10.11

In normal scenarios python's datetime.datetime.now() should return the local system time but in my scenario it is returning me UTC time even though the system is running in IST

[Sample case ran in the container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu4gd.png)

In the attached screenshot I am running the following code snippet

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

As seen in the screenshot the "date" command in the terminal returns an IST timestamp however the datetime.datetime.now() is returning an UTC timestamp.

Any idea on what can be the cause for this? This seems like an issue in this specific image as replicating the same on python3.10 on my local environment gives correct results.

Comment: Post the text in the screenshot here as text; there's no need to make it an image.

Comment: I'd guess container is set up to use UTC time which is a good default. I'd check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68996420/how-to-set-timezone-inside-alpine-base-docker-image or similar for setting appropriate timezone in your image. Or even better, [specify tz to use](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime)

Comment: It might be a good choice to use [aware datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects) in your code, giving you explicit control over used time zones. For Python, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63628816/10197418 for instance.